# Error pressing spacebar and using CellContentClick Event in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I'm programming in C# with VS2012. In one of the forms, there is a datagridview with a check column (DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn). Also, the CellContentClick event is captured for checking if CheckBox is checked or not at the same moment the user clicks. But a NullReferenceException occurs when the User press the Spacebar. I have debugged that, and the Expection occurs when all code has been executed correctly, in the last parenthesis.

The main problem is that I need to clear the DataGridView and re-fill it. If I change the event to CellValueChanged, it works correctly, but it isn't that I need

How can I solved this question?

The full code is this:

```cs
public partial class frm_datagrid : Form
{
    bool data_initialization = false;
    List<String> orders;

    public frm_datagrid(List<String> orders)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    private void frm_datagrid_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data_initialization = true;

        createDatagrid2(this.DataGrid_Orders);
        fillDatagrid(this.DataGrid_Orders, this.orders);


        data_initialization = false;
    }

    private void createDatagrid2(KryptonDataGridView dgv)
    {
        #region Datagrid Initialization
        Utils_Presentacion.createDataGridColumns(dgv, "DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn", "Check", "VR?", false, null);
        Utils_Presentacion.createDataGridColumns(dgv, "KryptonDataGridViewTextBoxColumn", "Order", "Order", true, null);


        dgv.Columns["Check"].Width = 45;
        dgv.Columns["Order"].Width = 85;


        // Columns Sort Mode
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
            col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        #endregion
    }

    private void fillDatagrid(KryptonDataGridView dgv, List<string> list)
    {
        data_initialization = true;

        dgv.Rows.Clear();

        dgv.Rows.Add();
        DataGridViewRow r = dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1];
        r.Cells["Check"].Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

        //r.Cells["Check"].Value = false;
        r.Cells["Order"].Value = "987w4927429";

        data_initialization = false;
    }


    private void DataGrid_Orders_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!data_initialization)
        {

            if (e.ColumnIndex == DataGrid_Orders.Columns["Check"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                changedValue2(sender, e.RowIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void changedValue2(object sender, int RowIndex)
    {
        if (!data_initialization)
        {
            // Get row values
            String value_check = valueOf("Check", RowIndex);
            String value_pedido = valueOf("Order", RowIndex);


            // Find the order and check or uncheck VR option
            foreach (String s in this.orders.ToList())
            {
                String order_number = s.Substring(20, 13);

                if (value_pedido == order_number)
                {
                    if (value_check != null && value_check.Trim().ToUpper() == "TRUE")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(s + "Checked");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(s + "NOT Checked");
                    }
                }
            }


            fillDatagrid(this.DataGrid_Orders, this.orders);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get an exception? Also, post the message of this exception.

Comment: The main problem is that when the user press the spacebar for changing the checkbox value occurs this Exception... I show the message "Check column is clicked", and when the debug is in the last parenthesis, press F10 for view the next sentence, then occurs the exception.   (in  System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.NotifyMASSClient(Point position))

Comment: Please, can you remove duplicate mark? The question isn't in another site, and there isn't a null object. I have seen that with CellValueChanged Event runs correctly, but with the CellContentClick event doesn't run... Maybe is a bug, but I don't know it... Because when I debug, there isn't any object with null value... and If I Continue with the execution, Datagrid is shown with the changes correctly... It is a bit rare... Also, I can't capture the Exception whit try-catch block, because it appears when all code has been executed ok.

Comment: 4 reopen votes already, 1 to go.